# Generate random path in 10 by 10 grid and fill up with uppercase characters in order

Tags: c, algorithm, random

Goal: To start  from top left, pick a random direction to walk 1 place, and place a character there. Then repeat the same until all 26 letters are used up. You cannot walk outside the grid or onto a cell which already has a letter. If all four sides are occupied, terminate the program.

What I tried:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 12
#define COLS 12

/*just run it*/

int main(void) {
    char grid[ROWS][COLS] = {};
    int current_col = 1;
    int current_row = 1;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    
    for (int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++) { for (int o = 0; o<COLS; o++) grid[i][o] = '.';}
    
    for (int i=65; i<=90; i++) {
        int dir = rand() % 4;
        
        while ((current_row == 1 && dir == 3)||
               (current_row == 11 && dir == 1)||
               (current_col == 1 && dir == 0)||
               (current_col == 11 && dir == 2)) dir = rand() % 4;
        
        if (grid[current_row+1][current_col] != '.'
            && grid[current_row-1][current_col] != '.'
            && grid[current_row][current_col+1] != '.'
            && grid[current_row][current_col-1] != '.') break;
        
        while ((dir == 1 && grid[current_row+1][current_col] != '.') || (dir == 3 && grid[current_row-1][current_col] != '.')) dir = rand() % 4;
        while ((dir == 2 && grid[current_row][current_col-1] != '.') || (dir == 0 && grid[current_row][current_col+1] != '.')) dir = rand() % 4;
        
        if (dir == 0) {grid[current_row][current_col] = (char)i; current_col--;}
        else if (dir == 1) {grid[current_row][current_col] = (char)i; current_row++;}
        else if (dir == 2) {grid[current_row][current_col] = (char)i; current_col++;}
        else if (dir == 3) {grid[current_row][current_col] = (char)i; current_row--;}
    } for (int i = 0; i<13; i++) {for (int o = 0; o<13; o++) printf("%c ",grid[i][o]); printf("\n");}
}
```

My output:

```
. A B . . . . . . . . . .
. D C . . . . . . . . . .
. E F . . . . . . . . . .
. H G . . . . . . . . . .
. I J . . . . . . . . . .
. . K P O . . . . . . . . 
. . . Q R . . . . . . . . 
. . . V W . . . . . . . .
. . . . X . . . . . . . . 
. . . Z Y . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Notice how after JK, L is skipped (well not skipped, it got written over by P). I see my code does not respect the condition of already occupied cells, but no idea to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that I think you should change:

Since you start from the top-left, `current_col` and `current_row` should be equal to 0 initially.

When checking whether all nearby cells are occupied:

```
if (grid[current_row+1][current_col] != '.'
            && grid[current_row-1][current_col] != '.'
            && grid[current_row][current_col+1] != '.'
            && grid[current_row][current_col-1] != '.') break;
```

If `current_row` or `current_col` is equal to 0 or 11, adding (or subtracting) 1 will result in out-of-bound indexing.

In these 2 while loop:

```
while ((dir == 1 && grid[current_row+1][current_col] != '.') || (dir == 3 && grid[current_row-1][current_col] != '.')) dir = rand() % 4;
while ((dir == 2 && grid[current_row][current_col-1] != '.') || (dir == 0 && grid[current_row][current_col+1] != '.')) dir = rand() % 4;
```

You are trying to randomize `dir` until you find a direction such that the next position is not occupied. But you split the process into 2 separate while loops. Hence after the second loop, `dir` can still be 1 or 3 despite the corresponding next position being occupied.

Here is another way to do this. I use `dx` and `dy` as direction change hence we can go through all 4 directions in the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ROWS 12
#define COLS 12

/*just run it*/

int main(void) {
    char grid[ROWS][COLS] = {};
    int current_col = 0;
    int current_row = 0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    
    for (int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++) { for (int o = 0; o<COLS; o++) grid[i][o] = '.';}
    int dx[4] = {0, 1, 0, -1};
    int dy[4] = {1, 0, -1, 0};
    for (int i=65; i<=90; i++) {
        // check if all directions are blocked
        bool all_blocked = true;
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            int next_row = current_row + dx[j];
            int next_col = current_col + dy[j];
            if (next_row >= 0 && next_row < ROWS && next_col >= 0 && next_col < COLS && grid[next_row][next_col] == '.'){
                all_blocked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (all_blocked) break;
        while(1){
            int dir = rand() % 4;
            int next_row = current_row + dx[dir];
            int next_col = current_col + dy[dir];
            if (next_row >= 0 && next_row < ROWS && next_col >= 0 && next_col < COLS && grid[next_row][next_col] == '.'){
                grid[next_row][next_col] = (char)i;
                current_row = next_row;
                current_col = next_col;
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++) {for (int o = 0; o<COLS; o++) printf("%c ",grid[i][o]); printf("\n");}
}
```

Output:

```
. A B . . . . . . . . . 
. . C D E . . . . . . . 
. . H G F . . . . . . . 
. . I . . . . . . . . . 
. . J . . . . . . . . . 
. . K L . . . . . . . . 
. . . M N . . . . . . . 
. . . P O . . . . . . . 
. . . Q . U V . . . . . 
. . . R S T W X Y Z . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: Actually, I used a 12 by 12 grid at start because I didn't wanna handle edge cases, so just padded the whole grid. In the final program, only the middle 10*10 grid will be printed. That's why i started with col and row = 1 starting. Besides that, should i try having an array of valid moves available, which would refresh for every character?

Comment: You could definitely create an array of valid moves available for every character. Then you don't need a while loop to choose a random direction (just choose a random element in the array). In terms of performance, there should not be much difference though.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your code does not respect the condition of already occupied cells because of this line:

```
while ((dir == 2 && grid[current_row][current_col-1] != '.') ||
       (dir == 0 && grid[current_row][current_col+1] != '.'))
       dir = rand() % 4;
```

Here, the direction does not match the column where you will end up. Direction 2 means current_col+1, direction 0 mean current_col-1, so your checks are inverted.

Beside that, there are two other notes:

- You are using only 11 out of the 12 cells of the grid. Maybe that's intended, but if it is not, you should change the starting cell to {0, 0} and also the first checks you make should see if `(current_row == 0 && dir == 3)` and `(current_col == 1 && dir == 0)`, otherwise you will never be able to go to the first row or column. Beware that at the end you are also printing 13 of the 12 cells, looping through indices from 0 to 12 (13 in total).
- You cannot separate all these checks one from the other. At first you are randomly generating a new direction to prevent that you exit from the grid. But then below you do 2 other loops where you generate a new random direction, that can go outside of the grid because you are not checking for that condition anymore.

This is a sample of a working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 12
#define COLS 12

int main(void) {
    char grid[ROWS][COLS] = {};
    int current_col = 0;
    int current_row = 0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    
    for (int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++)
        for (int o = 0; o<COLS; o++)
            grid[i][o] = '.';

    for (int i=65; i<=90; i++) {
        grid[current_row][current_col] = (char)i;
        
        char adjacent_cells[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        
        if (current_col > 0)
            adjacent_cells[0] = grid[current_row][current_col-1];
        if (current_row < ROWS - 1)
            adjacent_cells[1] = grid[current_row+1][current_col];
        if (current_col < COLS - 1)
            adjacent_cells[2] = grid[current_row][current_col+1];
        if (current_row > 0)
            adjacent_cells[3] = grid[current_row-1][current_col];
            
        int is_possible_to_continue = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (adjacent_cells[j] == '.')
            {
                is_possible_to_continue = 1;
                break;
            }
        if (is_possible_to_continue == 0)
            break;
    
        int dir = rand() % 4;
        while (adjacent_cells[dir] != '.')
            dir = rand() % 4;
        
        if (dir == 0) current_col--;
        else if (dir == 1) current_row++;
        else if (dir == 2) current_col++;
        else if (dir == 3) current_row--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int o = 0; o<COLS; o++)
            printf("%c ",grid[i][o]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, also, is there a way to initialize the whole array to '.' without the for loop?

Comment: You could use the [memset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) function, like this:
`memset(grid, '.', sizeof(grid));`
To use this you have to include the <string.h> library.